# Unity: How do I start my weapon reload countdown when I am reloading?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Timer that counts down every 3 seconds (The white circle). It has a script attached called ReloadTimer.

I have a script that fires bullets (TankShooter) and reloads for 3 seconds.

How do I make it so that my countdown starts when I am reloading?

I tried looking at a lot of Unity forums and the advice didn't work.

**ReloadTimer.cs**

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]

public class ReloadTimer : MonoBehaviour
{

public Image filled;
public Text text;
public float maxValue = 3;
public float value = 0;


// UpdateReload is called once per frame
public void UpdateReload ()
{

    value = Mathf.Clamp(value, 0, maxValue);
    float amount = value / maxValue;

    filled.fillAmount = amount;
    text.text = value.ToString();
}
}
```

**TankShooter**

```
public int m_PlayerNumber = 1;
public Rigidbody m_Shell;
public Transform m_FireTransform;
public AudioSource m_ShootingAudio;
public AudioClip m_FireClip;
public float m_ShellVelocity = 100f;

private string m_FireButton;

public int maxAmmo = 5;
private int currentAmmo;
public float reloadTime = 2f;
private bool isReloading = false;

public ReloadTimer reloadTimer;

public class TankShootingT : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public ReloadTimer reloadTimer;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (!isLocalPlayer)
        {
            return;
        }

        currentAmmo = maxAmmo;
        m_FireButton = "Fire" + m_PlayerNumber;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (isReloading) 
            return;

        if (currentAmmo <= 0)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Reload());


            return;
        }

        reloadTimer.UpdateReload();


        if (m_FireButton == "Fire1" && Input.GetButtonUp(m_FireButton))
        {
            // we released the button, have not fired yet
            CmdShoot();
        }

    }

    IEnumerator Reload()
    {
        isReloading = true;
        Debug.Log("Reloading...");

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(reloadTime);


        currentAmmo = maxAmmo;
        isReloading = false;
    }



    [Command]
    private void CmdShoot()
    {
        currentAmmo--;

        // Instantiate and launch the shell.
        Rigidbody shellInstance = Instantiate(m_Shell, m_FireTransform.position, m_FireTransform.rotation) as Rigidbody;

        shellInstance.velocity = m_ShellVelocity * m_FireTransform.forward;

        // Server spawns the shell
        NetworkServer.Spawn(shellInstance.gameObject);

        m_ShootingAudio.clip = m_FireClip;
        m_ShootingAudio.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get what the problem is? Do you have something like a GUI element (The white circle) that fills after 3 seconds of shooting (Something like a cool down time?)?

Comment: Yes. My white circle fills up every 3 seconds.

Comment: I need to link it to my TankFiring method so that the countdown starts when I am reloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, There isn't such thing as `UpdateReload` that would be "called once per frame" as this is not a predetermined Unity function, it is just a function that you created (You can read about this [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)). Another problem is that you didn't even call that function anywhere else in your scripts. And even if you did, `Mathf.Clamp()` needs to be placed in an `Update()` function so it can update it's value each frame.

I made some modifications to the scripts that you posted, but I haven't tested them yet. give it a try and let me know how it goes:

**ReloadTimer.cs**

```
public class ReloadTimer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static ReloadTimer Instance { set; get; }

    public Image filled;
    public Text text;
    public float coolDownTime = 3;

    public bool isCoolingDown = false;

    void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (isCoolingDown == true)
        {
            filled.fillAmount += 1.0f / coolDownTime * Time.deltaTime;

            int percentageInt = Mathf.RoundToInt((filled.fillAmount / coolDownTime) * 10);
            text.text = percentageInt.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

**TankShootingT.cs**

```
public int m_PlayerNumber = 1;
public Rigidbody m_Shell;
public Transform m_FireTransform;
public AudioSource m_ShootingAudio;
public AudioClip m_FireClip;
public float m_ShellVelocity = 100f;

private string m_FireButton;

public int maxAmmo = 5;
private int currentAmmo;
public float reloadTime = 2f;
private bool isReloading = false;

public ReloadTimer reloadTimer;

public class TankShootingT : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public ReloadTimer reloadTimer;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (!isLocalPlayer)
        {
            return;
        }

        currentAmmo = maxAmmo;
        m_FireButton = "Fire" + m_PlayerNumber;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (isReloading)
            return;

        if (currentAmmo <= 0)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Reload());


            return;
        }

        reloadTimer.UpdateReload();


        if (m_FireButton == "Fire1" && Input.GetButtonUp(m_FireButton))
        {
            // we released the button, have not fired yet
            CmdShoot();
        }

    }

    IEnumerator Reload()
    {
        isReloading = true;
        ReloadTimer.Instance.isCoolingDown = true;

        Debug.Log("Reloading...");

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(reloadTime);

        currentAmmo = maxAmmo;
        isReloading = false;

        ReloadTimer.Instance.isCoolingDown = false;
        ReloadTimer.Instance.filled.fillAmount = 0.0f;
    }



    [Command]
    private void CmdShoot()
    {
        currentAmmo--;

        // Instantiate and launch the shell.
        Rigidbody shellInstance = Instantiate(m_Shell, m_FireTransform.position, m_FireTransform.rotation) as Rigidbody;

        shellInstance.velocity = m_ShellVelocity * m_FireTransform.forward;

        // Server spawns the shell
        NetworkServer.Spawn(shellInstance.gameObject);

        m_ShootingAudio.clip = m_FireClip;
        m_ShootingAudio.Play();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps a bit.